# How User can add Order Line Note or at less Order Note or Metadata?

Tags: e-commerce, interaction, saleor

Does Saleor have some minimum implementation of interaction for receiving data from client

I need to receive some data from client for special product that will be created and send to him.

As for me the best way will be `order Line Note` editable by user

I've tried to add new fields to `CartLine` after to `CheckoutLine`, but it's not good way because i need to modify [@saleor/sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@saleor/sdk) in frontend and modify backend API.

I've tried to esaminate different custom fields like:

- `customerNote` (`OrderAddNote`)
- `OrderLine`
- `OrderLineInput`
- `OrderLineCreateInput`
- `CheckoutLine`
- `CheckoutLineInput`
- `CheckoutCreateInput`
- `MetaStore`
- `MetaItem`
- `MetaClientStore`
- `Metadata`

and found that in all of them some notes can create only stuff users.

My question is:

> What is the best way to have interaction with customer? If there is noting: Is it reasonable to change permission for Add Metadata o Add Note.

PS. How can I see metadata in dashboard orders

Answer (score 1):

Metadata can be created / updated for a checkout without any special permissions and can be seen and edited from the Dashboard. Customer notes can be used as well, but have less features.